# javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Internal error occurred

Tags: java, centos, jakarta-mail, imap, dovecot

I am trying to install `JavaMail` on a `CentOS 7` development machine using `localhost` only for the emails.  Towards this end, I have installed `dovecot`, `postfix`, and `mailx`.  I just installed `dovecot` using [the instructions in this tutorial](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/dovecot-installation-and-configuration-on-centos).  **But my `JavaMail` test code has been giving me all sorts of authentication errors when I try to read an inbox.  How can I resolve these authentication errors so that I can log in?**

At first, I was getting errors related to not finding a certificate, but I was able to resolve all those errors by commenting out any mention of `ssl` in the config files, by changing the protocol to `imap` instead of `imaps`, and by changing authentication to `plain` instead of `login`.  (I can do all these things because it is a development machine and I just want to get `JavaMail` working before adding security in afterwards.)  But after all those changes, I am still getting:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE Internal error occurred.   
Refer to server log for more information.
```

The line of code that throws the error is:

```
store.connect("localhost.localdomain", "root", "somepassword");
```

Note that typing `hostname` in the CentOS terminal results in `localhost.localdomain`.

The `/var/log/maillog` records are:

```
Jan  8 16:08:01 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<root>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=7965, secured, session=<yb8l8ywMdwB/AAAB>
Jan  8 16:08:01 localhost dovecot: imap: Error: user root: Invalid settings in userdb: userdb returned 0 as uid
Jan  8 16:08:01 localhost dovecot: imap: Error: Invalid user settings. Refer to server log for more information.
```

Comment: And what is in the dovecot logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dovecot won't let you log in as root. Use some other user and userid.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for the fast response.